# wysihtml5 in rails_admin shows tags instead of effects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin, wysihtml5

I'm using `sferik/rails_admin` gem & `wysihtml5` text field editor as it is described [here](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Wysihtml5).
Everything seems to work fine except one think. It doesnt work. For example in /admin page I see this:
[image: 1]

And on my page I see this:
[image: 2]

And the same trouble happens with all the effects. Even **bold text** I see as:
b> bold text /b>

Can you help me handle this? Thanks 4 your attension!

Comment: Hmmmm - how are you including the `wysihtml5` code in your asset pipeline? Is it included with `rails_admin`?

Comment: @RichPeck I'm including  bootstrap-wysihtml5.css &  bootstrap-wysihtml5.js to my assets folder

Comment: Okay, so they're independently added? Are they being called correctly from your <head> tags?

Comment: @RichPeck Yes, they are added independently. And yes, they are called in head & as I wrote it in application.js & application.css

Comment: Hmmmm how strange! I would then suggest that the JS is not binding to the element, but it's referenced in a strange way in the link you gave -- have you got any idea if `wysihtml5` is actually trying to bind or not?

Comment: No problem buddy! I was actually going to recommend the answer... but I thought it was too simplistic. Oh well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to output the html content in your view?

If I understand your problem, you might just need to add a `html_safe` call in the view.